# A characterization of Bessel sequences in a Hilbert space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, frame-theory

I've shown that if for a sequence $\{f_{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in a Hilbert space $H$ we have 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|\langle f,f_n\rangle|^{2}< \infty$$
for all $f\in H$ (i.e., it is a Bessel sequence in $H$), then
the map $T$ from $\mathcal{l}^2$ to $H$ sending $(a_n)$ to $\Sigma_n a_n f_n$ is well-defined, linear and bounded.

But I'd appreciate it if someone could guide me on how to prove the converse?

Comment: Isn't $\langle f_m, f_n\rangle$ a scalar? How can it define an operator? Also are you assuming that your sequence is bounded, or orthogonal or something?

Comment: There is no other assumption on $f_n$ other than that they satisfy $(1)$ for any $f\in H$.

Comment: I think you mean that the matrix with entries $\langle f_m, f_n\rangle$ defines a bounded operator when applied to a vector $f=(\langle f, e_k\rangle e_k)_k$ where $e_k$ is an orthonormal basis for $H$. Is this correct?

Comment: So for a sequence $a\in \mathcal{l}^2$, I think I can show that the map $Ta= \Sigma_n a_n f_n$ is well-defined, linear and bounded. Could you perhaps please provide a hint for the converse?

Comment: @graviola: Hi graviola. Hopefully the solution below works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $ \varphi: \mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{C} $ be **any** (continuous) linear functional on $ \mathcal{H} $. Then the composition
$$
\varphi \circ T =
\left\{ \begin{matrix}
{\ell^{2}}(\mathbb{N})     & \to     & \mathbb{C} \\
(a_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}} & \mapsto & \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}}
                                       a_{n} \varphi(f_{n})
\end{matrix} \right\}
$$
is a (continuous) linear functional on $ {\ell^{2}}(\mathbb{N}) $. It follows from the Riesz-Fréchet Theorem that
$$
(\spadesuit) \qquad
(\varphi(f_{n}))_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \in {\ell^{2}}(\mathbb{N}).
$$
Now, pick any $ f \in \mathcal{H} $ and let $ \varphi \stackrel{\text{df}}{=} \langle f,\bullet \rangle_{\mathcal{H}}: \mathcal{H} \to \mathbb{C} $. Then $ \varphi $ is a (continuous) linear functional on $ \mathcal{H} $, and so by $ (\spadesuit) $, we obtain
$$
    (\langle f,f_{n} \rangle_{\mathcal{H}})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}
\in {\ell^{2}}(\mathbb{N}),
$$
which is precisely the desired result.

Comment: Great answer, thanks!